# Not able to render child Node's, child Node using Umbraco XSLT

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco-blog, umbraco-contour

I have following Content structure

```
=Main Home Node 
-Child Node 1
-Child Node 2
-Child Node 3
 - - Sub Node 1 of Child 3
 - - Sub Node 2 of Child 3
 - - Sub Node 1 of Child 3
 -Child Node 4
```

I am rendering contains of Child Node which is Richtext Editor(Name = sectionBody)
,As following XSLT code to Render Child Node's.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">

<h2 class="section-title text-center wow fadeInDown"><xsl:value-of select="sectionHeading"/></h2>

         <div class="row">
                     <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:Item($currentPage/@id,'sectionBody')" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Now I am calling macro in Richtext Editor of Child Node 3 for Rendering contains of Sub Node of child Node 3

Following is XSLT macro code which I am using to render in Richtext Editro

```
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level = 2 ]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']"/>
            <div > Sub Node </div>
            <xsl:if test="count($items) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                            <xsl:if test="string-length($items/profileType) > 0">
    <div> In If of Sub Node</div>
                                        <xsl:variable name="Chkitems" select="umbraco.library:

Split($items/profileType,',')" />  
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$Chkitems"/>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$Chkitems//value">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                    </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
```

I am able preview out come of above macro rendering in  Richtext Editor.
But while render on the site, Its only show "Sub Node". but not the value of or inner div.

Where I am able to get value of Header "sectionHeading" but can not able to view "sectionBody"